# MS Dynamics CRM 2011 throws intermittent [CryptographicException: Unknown error "-1073741823".] when invoking REST API from BizTalk

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I'm calling the CRM REST API for changes in AuditSet via WCFWebHttp from two different BizTalk applications. Everything is configured identically for both applications

One application works fine without any exceptions, but the "new" one fails intermittently with the following exception:

===================================================

### MSCRM Error Report:

> Error: Unknown error "-1073741823".
>
> Error Message: Unknown error "-1073741823".
>
> Source File: Not available
>
> Line Number: Not available
>
> Request URL: http:///XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AuditSet?%24filter=CreatedOn+ge+datetime'2017-06-22T05%3a18%3a29'+and+CreatedOn+lt+datetime'2017-06-22T05%3a24%3a56'
>
> Stack Trace Info: [CryptographicException: Unknown error "-1073741823".]
>      at System.Security.Cryptography.BCryptNative.OpenAlgorithm(String algorithm, String implementation)
>      at System.Security.Cryptography.BCryptHashAlgorithm..ctor(CngAlgorithm algorithm, String implementation)
>      at System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Cng..ctor()
>      at System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(String password, String passwordFormat)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.MainApplication.Application_OnEndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs eventArguments)
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>
> [2017-06-22 15:24:57.870] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:  156 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: a3a47217-cf65-40d3-8993-5c9492791f6c | ExceptionConverter.ConvertMessageAndErrorCode  ilOffset = 0x23B
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #5A85F91A: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Unknown error "-1073741823".
>     at System.Security.Cryptography.BCryptNative.OpenAlgorithm(String algorithm, String implementation)
>     at System.Security.Cryptography.BCryptHashAlgorithm..ctor(CngAlgorithm algorithm, String implementation)
>     at System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Cng..ctor()
>     at System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(String password, String passwordFormat)
>     at Microsoft.Crm.MainApplication.Application_OnEndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs eventArguments)
>     at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

=========================================

I've used Fiddler to monitor the calls and there are no differences between calls which are successful and those which fails

Comment: And it only fails intermittently when using BizTalk calls it?  Or have you not tried it enough with Fiddler to reproduce it?   From what you have said and the error, it looks like it may be an issue at the CRM side to do with the password hashing, and nothing that BizTalk is doing that is causing it.

Comment: Yip, only fails in about 5% of the BT calls. If I paste the URI into a browser (impersonating the service account) I can invoke the service successfully every time.